# Fira Mono in LaTeX (LaTeX -> dvips -> ps2pdf)

Tags: fonts, dvips, ps2pdf

Is this possible to use the font `Fira Mono` in normal `LaTeX`, i.e., `LaTeX` -> `dvips` -> `PS2PDF`. I understand it can be used by using `XeLaTeX` or `LuaLaTeX`, but I need to use it in `dvips` format. Please advise....

Comment: Thanks it's working fine...New update for me.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fira Mono has a Type 1 version installed which can be loaded with `\usepackage{FiraMono}` (see the [Font Catalogue page](https://www.tug.org/FontCatalogue/firamono/)).  The font face is a bit larger than the standard Computer Modern, so I added a 0.82 scale factor as well:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.82]{FiraMono}
\begin{document}
Here's some code:
\begin{verbatim}
          \def\hello#1{Hello #1!}
    \mshow\hello
    \named\def\hello#[who]{Hello #[who]!}
    \mshow\hello
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Built with `latex -> dvips -> ps2pdf`, gives:

> [image]